# Dynamically building subtables in a table

Tags: lua

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically build a series of sub-tables inside a lua table. For example

```
function BuildsubTable()
   local oTable = {}
   local name  = {"P1","P2"}
  for i = 1, 2 do
    oTable[i] = {name = name[i], "x" = i + 2, "y" = i + 1}
  end
  return oTable
end
```

expected output:

```
 oTable = {
  {name = "P1", "x"=3, "y"=2},
  {name = "P2", "x"=4, "y"=3}
 }
```

Which obviously doesn't work, but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. This is a rather simple task but in LUA 5.3 this is proving to be difficult. I cannot find a good example of building a table in this manner. Any solutions or other ideas would be appreciated. In Python I would use a class or a simple dictionary.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Could you provide some sample expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you quote the string indices. The generic syntax for declaring a table key inside the table constructor is `[<key>] = <value>`, for example, `[20] = 20` or `["x"] = i + 2`.

A shorthand for `["<key>"] = <value>`, that is, for string indices that are valid variable names, you can write `<key> = <value>`, for example `x = i + 2`.

In your code you use a mix of both and write `{ ..., "x" = i + 2, ... }`. A quick google search shows me that in Python, which you mention, you quote string keys in dictionaries, so you probably mixed that up with Lua?

EDIT: I noticed this a bit late, but you can also use `ipairs` to iterate the first table and `table.insert` to insert values:

```
function BuildsubTable()
    local oTable = {}
    local name  = {"P1","P2"}
    for i,name in ipairs(name) do
        table.insert(oTable, {name = name, "x" = i + 2, "y" = i + 1})
    end
    return oTable
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
oTable[i] = {name = name[i], x = i + 2, y = i + 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys! I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

DarkWiiPlayers & lhf's answers are the proper way.
But here is how you can fix your current code if you intend to use a string as a key

```
function BuildsubTable()
   local oTable = {}
   local name  = {"P1","P2"}
  for i = 1, 2 do
    oTable[i] = {name = name[i], ["x"] = i + 2, ["y"] = i + 1}
  end
  return oTable
end
```

Output

```
{
    [1] = { ['name'] = 'P1', ['x'] = 3, ['y'] = 2},
    [2] = { ['name'] = 'P2', ['x'] = 4, ['y'] = 3}
}
```